# Flash messages not working with connect-session-sequelize

Tags: node.js, session, sequelize.js, flash-message

I have a node.js web app that is switchable between MongoDB and Sequelize (PostgreSQL) for sessions. For both, I also layer in connect-flash (also tried express-flash) middleware for flash messages.  In short, MongoDB works, Sequelize does not.

The app has a notion of "packages" that a user can edit.  After the user edits a package successfully, I set a flash message of

```
"${timestamp} Package ${pkgID} successfully updated."
```

and redirect. With Sequelize (connect-session-sequelize), the flash message does not display, even though I can see it in the database, and if I refresh the page, then it *does* appear.

Here is the setup for Sequelize sessions:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expSession = require('express-session');
var flash = require('express-flash');

app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET));

if (sessionDBVendor === 'postgres') {
    let models = require('./models/postgres');
    var SequelizeSessionStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(expSession.Store);
    var sequelizeSessionStore = new SequelizeSessionStore({
        db: models.sequelize,
        table: 'Session'
    });
    sequelizeSessionStore.on('set', function (data) {
        debug(`SequelizeSessionStore: Session ${data} UPDATED.`);
    });
    app.use(
        expSession({
            secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
            store: sequelizeSessionStore,
            resave: false, // we support the touch method so per the express-session docs this should be set to false 
            proxy: false, // if you do SSL outside of node.
            saveUninitialized: false,
        })
    );
}
app.use(flash());
```

Looking at connect-session-sequelize source code, I found that I could add "connect:session-sequelize" to my DEBUG environment variable to get extra info in the console.  Here is the interesting part of the console log, with some formatting, some blank lines and numbers added.

```
      connect:session-sequelize INSERT "DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI" +5s
    Executing (default): SELECT "sid", "userId", "expires", "data", "createdAt", "updatedAt" 
            FROM "webjmp"."sessions" AS "Session" 
            WHERE "Session"."sid" = 'DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI';
      connect:session-sequelize SELECT "DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI" +10ms
    Executing (default): SELECT "sid", "userId", "expires", "data", "createdAt", "updatedAt" 
            FROM "webjmp"."sessions" AS "Session" 
            WHERE "Session"."sid" = 'DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI';

(1)
    Executing (default): UPDATE "webjmp"."sessions" SET "expires"='2017-02-21 15:53:54.738 +00:00',
            "data"='{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},
               "flash":{"flashSuccess":["{02/20/2017 10:53:49} Package 58a718a0280081343eeab6d9 was successfully updated."]}}',
            "updatedAt"='2017-02-20 15:53:54.756 +00:00' WHERE "sid" = 'DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI'

(2)
      connect:session-sequelize FOUND DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI with data 
         {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"flash":{}} +17ms

    Executing (default): SELECT "Package"."_id", "Package"."title", "Package"."description", 
            {content removed for brevity}
            FROM "webjmp"."packages" AS "Package" 
            {content removed for brevity}
            ORDER BY "Package"."timestamp" DESC;
    ::1 - - [20/Feb/2017:15:53:54 +0000] "POST /packages/58a718a0280081343eeab6d9 HTTP/1.1" 302 62
      packages ID of package in returned list: 58a718a0280081343eeab6d9 +166ms
      packages ID of package in returned list: 58a716c35326d0b0380c0b37 +0ms
      packages ID of package in returned list: 58a474c55c9f18cc31cb0e2a +0ms
      packages ID of package in returned list: 58a45dfa51f335c015d8591f +0ms
      packages ID of package in returned list: 589cc7f30a333d1864b07bb2 +0ms

(3)
      packages listPackages: flashSuccess: [] +0ms

      connect:session-sequelize TOUCH "DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI" +92ms
    Executing (default): UPDATE "webjmp"."sessions" SET "expires"='2017-02-21 15:53:55.023 +00:00',
            "updatedAt"='2017-02-20 15:53:55.024 +00:00' 
            WHERE "sid" = 'DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI'
    ::1 - - [20/Feb/2017:15:53:55 +0000] "GET /packages HTTP/1.1" 200 6909
      connect:session-sequelize SELECT "DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI" +14ms
    Executing (default): SELECT "sid", "userId", "expires", "data", "createdAt", "updatedAt" 
            FROM "webjmp"."sessions" AS "Session" 
            WHERE "Session"."sid" = 'DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI';
      connect:session-sequelize SELECT "DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI" +6ms
    Executing (default): SELECT "sid", "userId", "expires", "data", "createdAt", "updatedAt" 
            FROM "webjmp"."sessions" AS "Session" WHERE "Session"."sid" = 'DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI';

(4)
      connect:session-sequelize FOUND DnVIEQiTfaxKZjYgC7uHmKbelJvJBzrI with data 
            {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},
            "flash":{"flashSuccess":["{02/20/2017 10:53:49} Package 58a718a0280081343eeab6d9 was successfully updated."]}} +3ms
```

Note that at (1), an UPDATE is done, and in the "data" for the update, "flash" contains an object:

```
"flash":{"flashSuccess":["{02/20/2017 10:53:49} Package 58a718a0280081343eeab6d9 was successfully updated."]}
```

That is my flash message.  However, note at (2), connect-session-sequelize debug spits out a FOUND message showing the session that it found, and in the session object it shows, flash is *empty*:

```
"flash":{}
```

Just after that, at (3), my code attempts to retrieve the "flashSuccess" flash message, but it comes up with an empty array.  But then, at (4), connect-session-sequelize spits out another FOUND debug message, and this one has the flash message in it:

```
"flash":{"flashSuccess":["{02/20/2017 10:53:49} Package 58a718a0280081343eeab6d9 was successfully updated."]}
```

and if I check the database, there it is.

It is almost as though the UPDATE that is setting the flash message is happening asynchronously and has not completed by the time the session is retrieved at (2), but then later it shows up.  But I tried throwing a setTimeout() in after the setting the flash message, to no avail.

Any ideas what's going on here?

UPDATE: I added a third session storage option that uses the connect-pg-simple middleware to store sessions in PostgreSQL.  With that option, flash messages work just fine.  connect-session-sequelize seems to be the odd man out.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question here, but it was pointed out on the [issues board for connect-session-sequelize](https://github.com/mweibel/connect-session-sequelize/issues/20) that express-session has a race condition in these flash message scenarios, and one needs to call req.session.save(cb) after setting flash messages, returning the response in the callback, to avoid the condition.  For example:

```
req.flash('flashError', err.message);
req.session.save(function() {
    res.redirect('/packages');
});
```

Doing so solved the problem.